Choosing especific value from DataExtension to use on Jorney
I have an Data Extension that uses 2 primary keys. One is an identifier of the customer, the other one is the product id.
I have a status on this table and I use it on a journey that informs the client about the status of the product
I dont wanna to ask client more them one time, so I selected reentry after exit.
The product status updates over time, so I need to use contact data and get the status field from the Data Extension. The problem is that I cant make the communication get the status of the right product ID, it gets the most recent status of a product attached to the costumer on the Data Extension.
Trying to exemplify, my DE is as follow:
CustomerID|ObjectID|ObjectStatus
1         | 1      | Sent
1         | 2      | Processing
1         | 3      | Arrived
And, on my journey I am using Object ID 2, for example, but when Object ID 3 updated my communication tells that the status is arrived

Can you try to explain specifically what you are trying to achieve here?
Where is this logic used in the journey? Entry filter, decision split, personalized content in e-mail?
